# Company asking us to share clothes - what to do?

Tags: retail, uniforms

My job currently is making all cashiers share a vest which meaning everyone is wearing it without being washed. Which is completely unsanitary. Is there anything against that saying they can't make us wear them. And if we refuse to wear it they send us home without pay.

What can I do about this?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: See past discussion of work uniforms for some related comments. Also, what's your actual question?

Comment: @keshlam I've reviewed this question. See here for an edit: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/7854

Comment: "if we refuse to wear it they send us home without pay" - can you clarify what happened in this exchange? You: "I don't want to wear this vest because it isn't clean." Employer: "You are being sent home without pay.". Did you complain about it and something like that really happened?

Comment: Will the store let you buy your own vest?

Comment: When you say "we" do you mean you and a few other folks attempted to not wear the vest and got sent home? My thought is if more than one person is complaining then you have a stronger case against management than if you fought alone.

Comment: unsanitary? Come on, it's not underwear. It's something that's going on over clothes, like an apron. I've seen plenty of cases where someone grabs a hi-viz vest before escorting kids across the road, or puts on the "I'm the volunteer" vest when they get to the booth. What are you going to catch from that?" It might be more convenient to have one each, but "health hazard" is taking things too far.

Comment: @KateGregory I agree to some extent. When I was working at mcdonalds as a teen we had to wear a special glove when emptying the grease trap. Also the freezer has a jacket hanging for anyone to use. However, we were never forced to wear or use these articles to the extent of being sent home without pay.

Comment: @KateGregory  Yes, unsanitary.  I'm surprised everyone doesn't know this.  Would you wear someone else's T-shirt?

Comment: @RichardU I repeat, it's not underwear. It's not against your skin. It is over your clothes. It is really not going to have an opportunity to collect anything yucky or pass that on to you. How would it? It may be inconvenient or annoying that there are not individual vests, but it's not a health hazard.

Comment: In my forestry days there was all sorts of unwashed gear we had to use at different times, gloves, helmets, goggles, vests etc,. refusing to wear them would get you sent home without pay, probably permanently.

Comment: @KateGregory Have you ever had a class on contageons?  Do you think a T-Shirt is a magical barrier?  It doesn't have to be against your skin, and you still have to touch it with your hands to put it on.  Germs are transferred from you, to the vest and from the vest to the next person.  I can't believe I have to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thats unfortunate. Can your store really not afford another vest?

You can try (and should try first) to solve this non confrontationally. You can make the case that its hurting producitivity (shared vest means infections spread faster -> more people take more sick days) and that vests aren't very expensive.

I know it might hurt, but if all other attempts at convincing them not to do this don't work, depending on how expensive that vest is, you could offer to buy your own for yourself.

As for the legality of this (I am not a lawyer, so take this with a grain of salt) it depends on your country. Multiple countrys in the EU for instance have workplace health regulations that would cover this under being a needless hazard to your health. Your mileage may vary in the US though. (You can still consult a lawyer about it if you're feeling that strongly)

Comment: +1 In the US, OSHA would be all over this like a bad rash.  OSHA has an anonymous hotline that someone can call to report workplace safety.  YMWV on this, these are federal work safety standards

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If they're not cleaning the vest, OSHA will get involved.  It's a health hazard.  Share a vest and you're sharing contagions.  OSHA is CLEAR on that.  visit their site.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the Canadian Centre for occupational health also goes into some detail on this.