# Sharing the same clothing with others

Tags: professionalism, canada

I work with 30 colleagues in a grocery store. Our management wants us to start wearing shared company-provided aprons, which wrap around the neck. Many of my coworkers including myself, find this dirty. Not all of my coworkers care about their hygiene equally. Some of them have unhygienic hair or strong body odors. The aprons will be washed only when needed.

I don't agree with this. My coworkers and I would like to refuse to wear these aprons on the grounds that they are unhygienic. Do we have the option of refusing or are we simply forced to wear the aprons if we want to work here?

Comment: " Can we refuse to wear them for those reasons or not?" Yes. You can even refuse to wear it for no reason at all. However, another important question to ponder: "Can your employer fire you for refusing to wear the apron?" Maybe or maybe not. Depends on the local laws, in other words, you need to specify your location.

Comment: How many aprons are there for the thirty women?

Comment: Why not take one apron for yourself, take it home, wash it, and keep it. When you leave the employment, then return it to the store. Otherwise, buy a similar apron (or two), and use them instead.

Comment: Is it possible that you take/keep the apron outside of the workplace? I mean, taking it home and washing it yourself anytime it's needed?

Comment: Country? - Generally you get a uniform with embroidered name and a locker for your personal effects, but if it's just a one size fits all then I suppose they view them as interchangeable. I wouldn't want to work or shop at a grocery store where people appeared unhygienic. If they don't have a bathing and wash hands rule you should work elsewhere.

Comment: @JWW That's a good idea, but I would make sure to OK it with management first.  Otherwise, you might end up on the wrong end of a theft complaint.  (Petty complaint, granted, but I've heard of pettier issues getting someone fired.)

Comment: I live in Canada and 1 employer is to take all the aprons home to clean once they are dirty. I find this request to share aprons ridiculous

Comment: "We are promoting knives for Master Chef Canada." Chefs own the knives they use and carry them to work. They do not trust anyone else to sharpen, clean, and polish them. No Chef ever touches another Chef's knife much less asks to borrow it. - You cannot possibly promote something called "Master Chef's Knives" while wearing a filthy *shared* apron.

Comment: Can't bring your own apron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Company asking us to share clothes - what to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67074/company-asking-us-to-share-clothes-what-to-do)

Answer (score 20):

> Can we refuse to wear them for those reasons or not?

You can... and either:

- nothing happens...
- you never get promoted.
- you can be fired.

I would **not** throw in my manager's face an out-of-the-blue plain NO.
I'd rather explain why it could be better to do it another way. For instance:

> Hi Alice/Bob, I noticed that our aprons are not always crisp and tidy. It's not only bad hygiene for our customers and us (employees), but also a bad image for our company. Could we be assigned the same apron at all time, so we take care of it? If not, do you think, for the ones who are willing to do so, that we could take/keep the apron outside of the workplace? Like taking it home, washing and ironing it by ourself anytime it's needed?

This way, you deflect: no one is accused of anything, and you show your concern about the customers, the company, and your colleagues. *You don't complain, you offer a solution*.

From there, it will depend on your manager's answer, and we can't tell you right now...

Comment: We are promoting knives for Master Chef Canada. We have the panflet right at our tills which display the cost and the points you can use towards them. The panflets are at the tills, which the cashier can explain how it works. I have 30 woman that work underneath me and they are livid about the whole situation, including myself.

Comment: Hm, I would be careful to offer to wash the aprons myself - that should be the shop's responsibility. If you only have one or two per person, you may need to wash them almost every day, which can be a lot of work - so I'd rather ask for them to be cleaned more frequently, and assigned to employees, than offer to do it myself without compensation.

Comment: @sleske It is widely accepted and often expected, in the US at least, for employees to care for their own uniform.

Answer (score 4):

You can refuse to do anything you want at work, but that can be career limiting.

Take your concerns to your supervisor before outright defiance and move forwards from their solution or lack of solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we refuse to wear them for those reasons or not?

In most companies, you cannot refuse to wear the uniform or promotional costume and still keep your job. You could ask, but it's doubtful.

> They will be washed only when needed. I don't agree with this.

If it were me, I'd consider asking if I could take one home each night to wash and wear it the next day.

And if that worked out, I'd then ask management if they would consider purchasing an additional apron for me so that I wouldn't have to wash it every night.

Comment: Not sure I'd say it's uniform but more a promotional costume. As far as I understand they are only wearing it to promote the item on sale. Similar, but different in my eyes